# How to draw from a thread, but smarter?

Tags: c#, multithreading, drawing

```
    private void DisplayThread()
    {
        while (RunDisplayThread)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(30);
            MPLastMessage.Text = MPTemplate.MPRET[(int)MP.MPReturn];
            Invoked();
            TickCount++;
            TickCountLabel.Text = string.Format("Tick Count: {0}", TickCount);
        }
    }

    private void Invoked()
    {
        while (MP.Drawing) { };
        g.DrawImage(MP.offscreen, 50, this.Height-300);
    }
```

So, this works, but after reading this,

[Draw image on a form from a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035087/draw-image-on-a-form-from-a-separate-thread)

I am clearly doing this in a less-than-intelligent way. Can anyone explain what the difference is between the suggested answer and what I'm doing? I've been teaching myself C#, and I'm at a loss for how that answer works.

Comment: It's rather hard to discern what you are intending to do here. The code appears out of thin air with no explanation of its purpose. And there's a link to some apparently unrelated question. Please, explain the background, motivate the question, and then ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

Although the link you provided is named "draw (...) from a separate thread", the drawing itself still happens on the Gui thread, using `Control.Invoke()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx).

Your `Invoked()` method runs on the "DisplayThread". I don't know where the `g` variable comes from though, is this a class variable set in the `OnPaint` method? If so chances are the `DrawImage` would fail if it would take more time than the code in `OnPaint`.